# MySQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE multiple keys

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following problem:

I have a MySQL table with columns id, uuid, responseId and response, where id is the primary key. Now I want to insert values into this table, respectively update the value response, if uuid and responseId are the same of the passed parameters. I have already thought of INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY, but my key is then the id.

Is there a way to solve my problem without first making a statement whether corresponding values exist, and then a second statement in which either insert or update is executed?

Comment: INSERT .. ODKU checks duplicate violation by **any** unique index. It can be either primary or regular unique. If there is more than one such index in the table then any index violation fires ODKU action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but id is the only unique key. It's not possible to set the other ones unique.

Comment: No unique key - no ODKU. It will fire never. Use stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in Comments, IODKU (aka upsert) would require `UNIQUE(uuid, responseId)`.

Without that, you can come close with this:

```
INSERT INTO real_table
    SELECT u.*  FROM updates AS u
           LEFT JOIN real_table AS r
             ON u.uuid = r.uuid
            AND u.responseId = r.responseId
        WHERE r.uuid IS NULL;
```

Caution:  Since there is no unique index on that pair of columns, there is an ambiguity of what to do if there are *multiple* rows with the same value of that pair -- either in `real_table` or in `updates`.